# Are hobby NiMH battery packs wired in series or parallel?

Tags: batteries

There is no indication on any battery packs for sale I have found that say if they are wired in series or parallel. I need to know this to make sure some cells are not discharging more/less than others because I can't charge them separately. Is there any way you can tell or is it just wired a certain way for most products?

[Battery pack I was looking at.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003BHIOCU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one NiMH cell is 1.2V, a 4.8V pack with four cells clearly has four cells in series.